# How can I get and set the selected radio button in external HTML content through actionscript?

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am new in flash and as3.

I am using an external html file through mx:html in Flash.

```
<fx:Script>
...
myHTML.location = "../assets/myHTML.htm";
...
</fx:Script>

<mx:HTML id="myHTML"/>
```

There are 3 radio buttons in this myHTML.htm file.

Is there any way to get and set the selected radio button through actionscript?

I am developing an AIR application. And as far as I come to know that the ExternalAPI will not work. Actually I want to use multiple HTML files of quiz question with radio buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody tell me this simple code:

In Flex/Actionscript:

```
function initial():void
{
html.addEventListener(Event.HTML_DOM_INITIALIZE,loaded);
}

function loaded(e:Event):void
{
html.htmlLoader.window.getOption = getOption;
}

function setvalue():void
{
html.htmlLoader.window.selectradio(radioButtonID);
}

function getOption(value:String):void
{
trace(value);
}
```

in HTML file

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function selectradio(selectvalue)
{
document.getElementById(selectvalue).checked = true;
}
</SCRIPT>

<INPUT ID="a" TYPE="radio" NAME="op" onClick="getOption('a')"
```

Answer (score 0):

With some hesitancy to answer due to lack of MXML experience and its applications, I would look into AS3's ExternalInterface http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html and its use within Flex http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=passingarguments_4.html

Comment: Actually I am developing an AIR application. And as far as I come to know that the ExternalAPI will not work. Actually I want to use multiple HTML files of quiz question with radio buttons.